smtp server fehler 451 (471 Tempary lookup failer
ich folgendes Problem beim versenden von eMail's bekomme ich folgende Fehlermeldung 451, 471 (Tempary lookup Failer). Woran kann es liegen das keine Mail's versendet werden ?
Rolli von RME

Please post questions and answers in English.
